# Tooltip add second style

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles, tooltip

I have 2 tooltips on my page, I'm currently using the code below but I wanted to add a second 'rel=' somehow so I don't have to duplicate all the jQuery, the plan was to add one div with the tooltip id as shown in the code and one with an extra class of tooltip2 so that one could be styles differently. I've fiddled around this this quite a bit and just can't work out how to get a separate class in there.

The main aim is make tooltip 2 black with white text for the popup.

I've also got a jsfiddle for it which I've been working on: http://jsfiddle.net/XJZ9v/

jQuery:

```
  $( document ).ready( function()
  {
     var targets = $( '[rel~=tooltip]' ),
         target  = false,
         tooltip = false,
         title   = false;

     targets.bind( 'mouseenter', function()
     {
         target  = $( this );
         tip     = target.attr( 'title' );
         tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );

         if( !tip || tip == '' )
             return false;

         target.removeAttr( 'title' );
         tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
                .html( tip )
                .appendTo( 'body' );

         var init_tooltip = function()
         {
             if( $( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', $( window ).width() / 2 );
             else
                 tooltip.css( 'max-width', 340 );

             var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
                 pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;

             if( pos_left < 0 )
             {
                 pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
                 tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
             }
             else
                 tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );

             if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() )
             {
                 pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
                 tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
             }
             else
                 tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );

             if( pos_top < 0 )
             {
                 var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
                 tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
             }
             else
                 tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );

             tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
                    .animate( { top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50 );
         };

         init_tooltip();
         $( window ).resize( init_tooltip );

         var remove_tooltip = function()
         {
             tooltip.animate( { top: '-=10', opacity: 0 }, 50, function()
             {
                 $( this ).remove();
             });

             target.attr( 'title', tip );
         };

         target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
         tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip );
     });
 });
```

CSS:

```
 .infoToolTip{
background-color: #D7DF23;
display: inline-block;
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
color: #000;
line-height: 28px;
font-size: 28px;
padding: 2px 5px 8px 5px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-family: 'IM Fell English', serif;
font-style: italic;
margin: -5px 0 -5px 5px;
font-weight: normal;
cursor: default;
-webkit-border-radius: 14px;
-moz-border-radius: 14px;
border-radius: 14px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
z-index: 1;
text-decoration: none;
 }


 .bondTen
 {
     text-align: center;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     background: #000000;

 }

 .bondTen:after /* triangle decoration */
 {
    border-top: 10px solid #000000;
}

 #tooltip
 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
     background: #D7DF23;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 100;
     padding: 15px;
 }

#tooltip:after /* triangle decoration */
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #D7DF23;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }

    #tooltip.top:after
    {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid #D7DF23;
        top: -20px;
        bottom: auto;
    }

    #tooltip.left:after
    {
        left: 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #tooltip.right:after
    {
        right: 10px;
        left: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .bondTenTooltip{
        float: none !important;
        font-family: 'ChevinProDemiBold';
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 0 5px 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background-color: #FFF;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        color: #666;
        line-height: 28px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        font-style: normal;
        margin: -5px 0 -5px 25px;
        font-weight: normal;
        cursor: default;
        -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
        -moz-border-radius: 14px;
        border-radius: 14px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <abbr title="Tooltip 1" class="bondTenTooltip" rel="tooltip">1</abbr>

  <abbr title="Tooltip 2" class="bondTenTooltip" rel="tooltip">2</abbr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add one more class you already have against `Tooltip 2`:

```
 <abbr title="Tooltip 2" class="bondTenTooltip bondTen" rel="tooltip">2</abbr>
```

And move `.bondTen` class declaration after `.bondTenTooltip`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJZ9v/1/)

Additionally, if you want to change tooltip itself, take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XJZ9v/4/)

**Edit** Fixed to work in chrome. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJZ9v/5/)

Comment: It's the popup div i need to be white on black which is what makes it a bit trickier than that and the <div> is added on hover

Comment: @huddds Did you looked at second link?

Comment: Yeah the popups dont seem to work at all in that JS, at least not on my crome browser, haven't tried any others

Comment: I've only tested in firefox. I'll fix and post results

Comment: Thanks, that's the type of thing I was after